# Html pattern regex allow numeric only

Tags: html, regex

I have an input type for contact number:

```
<input type="number" name="usercontact" placeholder="Contact Number" pattern="[0-9]{8,20}" />
```

I already put the pattern `[0-9]{8,20}` and i assume it don't allow other characters

But somehow e, and . (dot) able to pass through, why so? How should i only allow numbers only?

Comment: `type="number"` and `pattern` are used for validation. The user can enter anything, but at submitting, will receive validation error (usually red shadow around the field, and a message about the error).

Answer (score 0):

Input type number can accept e or E and floating point numbers , negative symbols.

Pattern can be used for the validation.You can check if the entered value is valid.

> According to [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) the pattern attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text, search, tel, url, email, or password, otherwise it is ignored.But this works in some browser.

```js
$('#numericInput').on('change keyup', function(event) {
    if ( event.target.validity.valid ) {
        $('#errorMsg').text($(this).val());
    } else {
        $('#errorMsg').text('invalid');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">

<input type="number" name="usercontact" placeholder="Contact Number" pattern="[0-9]{8,20}" id="numericInput" />
<p id="errorMsg"></p>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <input
        type="number"
        name="username"
        placeholder="Username"
        pattern="[0-9]{1,15}"
        id="username">
```